# Sending server-to-server events to AppsFlyer

Tags: ios, appsflyer, server-to-server, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I'm trying to sending server-to-server events to AppsFlyer for subscription notifications. For now I caught user subscription data from my API end point. According to below article I have to append 'appsflyer_id' and  'customer_user_id' with appsflyer request. These Ids generated when user launching app. How I know which user performed which event ? In subscription receipt not hold any user's private data. How I map 'appsflyer_id' and  'customer_user_id' with subscription receipt?

article:https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001279189-Subscription-Tracking-Guide#servertoserver